# Xubuntu Wifi drops out randomly but shows a good connection

Tags: networking, wireless, xubuntu

I have been having this problem for a while now.. Basically my WiFi on my laptop would randomly stop working but the icon would still show 4 bars until i disable networking. When i turn networking back on it will just show the spinning wheel and do nothing. Sometimes the connection pops back  in but i would like to find a fix for this as i don't want to keep having this problem. If its any help i have a HP 2000 Notebook and i use my notebook to share its WiFi connection with my Xbox. I have tried restarting my router which seems to help sometimes but the WiFi would just drop out again. Some days it will  stay on for the whole time i'm using the WiFi and days like today  it drops out constantly.

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company AR9485/HB125 802.11bgn 1×1 Wi-Fi Adapter [103c:1838]
 Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

Changed the Channel to 6 as it was on AUTO  before.

Update-This didn't solve the problem as my xubuntu laptop just lost WiFi for about 10 seconds then popped back in.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: 07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company AR9485/HB125 802.11bgn 1×1 Wi-Fi Adapter [103c:1838]
 Kernel driver in use: ath9k

Comment: It is not `spci` it is `lspci`. Copy and paste more carefully. And post the result TO YOUR QUESTION.

Comment: sorry edited...

Comment: This may be an interference with other networks. Try to change channel in your router.

Comment: could you explain how?

Comment: Go to your router settings. It is not related to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

OK i narrowed it down to a Router issue as my brother said the connection was dropping out for him as well and he runs windows 10 so thanks for the help Pilot.